# Java application from local machine to the server

Tags: java-server

I am developing an application in Java on a local machine. This is my first project, and I am afraid I started it in a wrong way, since I will have to install it on every machine, which can reveal such issues as Java versions incompatibility or even its absence on some machines. Besides, I would like to write the GUI in HTML.

So, I've decided it'd be better to write a server side application and open it in the browser. All users are connected to the server via LAN.

I would like to use something like WAMP, but in Java. I've never written web applications in Java.

Could you please help me with advice, which technology I should use (JSP, Apache Tomcat, something else), what kind of problems I can meet transferring the existing code into the server (I use a lot of external libraries, like Apache POI, Jsoup, HttpClient, etc), and tutorials on Java server programming (I've found so many information, I just do not know where I should start learning).

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am currently developing using spring. I think it's a good tool.

http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/index.html

http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html

good luck in your app